# How to combine Lucene & Hunspell to conduct search in PDF documents?

Tags: java, dictionary, lucene, information-retrieval, hunspell

I am trying to implement hunspell into lucene. The task is to make an application which finds words in pdf documents. I know what I have to do generaly but not specific.
I know that I have to make a list with indexes which contain the root of the words of the documents, and then search in that list.

But: I am a java beginner so I don't really have an idea how to start.
Every advice would be helpful.

Comment: I took a quick look at the Lucene API to see what's going on (your project seems interesting). The only thing I've found in such a short time is that [Lucene has a quality package documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html#package_description), maybe you can start out there.

Comment: Are you trying to make sure spelling errors in a PDF file are indexed as the most-likely correction? Or as a most-likely correction AND as the term as it appears?